# How to stop the motion of a UISlider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I want to stop the motion of a `UISlider` when a particular value is reached. After that it shouldn't move here and there. I mean I want to stop the `userInteraction` of a `UISlider` after a particular value is reached. How can I do it?

I used

```
myslider.userInteractionEnable=NO;
```

and

```
myslider.enabled=NO;
```

but still, I can move my slider. Please Help.

Comment: set the maximum range you want.. your particular value...

Comment: I second @Alfa, as you wouldn't want to stop the user from being able to move the slider half way through - they may think there is a problem.

Comment: if you still want you can create your custom slider...by adding a pan image view over a view...and then pan in particular region...

Comment: The similar solution is provided in the following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950577/stop-uislider-at-value

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could set disabled to YES to achieve your goal, but it might be better play with the minimum and maximum values instead of stopping the user from interacting with the control while he is changing its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following code:

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(modifySliderValue) forControlEvents: UIControlEventAllEvents];

- (void)modifySliderValue{
if(mySlider.value > 60) {
    mySlider.value = 60;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add at action to the `valueChanged` event like this:

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And then implement the method like this:

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{
    if (sender.value >= YOUR_MAX_VALUE)
    {
        sender.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

By the `userInteraction` property to `NO` you should be able to disable the touch events on it. Otherwise you might have some other code setting it to `YES` again.