# UISlider stop change value

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a UISlider and I want it to stop at a certain value. This is not the maximum, but a number that is available programmatically.

Example: UISlider has a max value of 100. The stop value is 20. Therefore, the user shouldn't be able to drag beyond 20.

my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var precentLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var precentSlider: UISlider!

var maxValuePrecent: Float = 20
override func awakeFromNib() {
    precentSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.updateKmsLabel(sender:)), for: .allEvents)
}

// To use
    @objc func updateKmsLabel(sender: UISlider!) {
        let value = Int(sender.value)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.precentLbl.text = String(value) + "%"
        }

        if Float(value) > maxValuePrecent {
            precentSlider.isEnabled = false //don't work
            precentSlider.endEditing(true) //don't work
            precentSlider.isContinuous = false //don't work
            precentSlider.isSelected = false //don't work
        }
    }
```

[this variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950577/stop-uislider-at-value) doesn't help me

Comment: if precentSlider.value > 20.0 {
 precentSlider.value = 20.0
}

Comment: @el-tomato : Post it as answer :) Tested ur code works fine

Comment: @Исмаил-Хасбулатов : Intersting question n very interesting answer :) hence +1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@objc func updateKmsLabel(sender: UISlider!) {
        let value = Int(sender.value)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.precentLbl.text = String(value) + "%"
        }

        if Float(value) >= maxValuePrecent {
            precentSlider.isEnabled = false //don't work
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.precentLbl.text = "\(maxValuePrecent)%"
                sender.value = maxValuePrecent
            }
            }

        }
```